# final variable in for statement in Java 5 and 6

Tags: java

Any idea why this compiles in Java 5 but not in Java 6?

```
for(final int k=0; k<10; k++);
```

What's the logic behind this? Any change to the scope of the variables between Java 5 and 6?

I cannot find anything in Sun documentations regarding this.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile in Java 5...

Comment: And it's not a matter of scope.

Comment: I can't understand why you would even want to mark that variable as final in that statement.

Answer (score 5):

For me it doesn't compile either with Java 6 or Java 1.3.1. (I don't have easy access to other versions.)

I very much doubt it would compile with any "normal" version of `javac` - the `k++` part of the loop is invalid as `k` is declared final.

Are you *sure* you got it to compile under Java 5? Which exact version, on what platform? Were you using an IDE, or was it from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't compile in any version of Java, because of the `k++`.

Are you sure you didn't get it mixed up with the for-each loop? Because the following does compile in Java 5 and up:

```
for (final int k : someIntArray) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like they fixed a bug.  It shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile on Java 5 either.